# Firebase cloud function deploy error - HTTP Error: 400, Invalid JSON payload received

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am using the [stripe-firestore-invoices](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/tree/master/firestore-stripe-invoices) cloud function in my project. I needed to customize it to satisfy my use case, so instead of installing the extension, I had downloaded the source code and tried deploying.
However, the function to [send the invoice](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-invoices/functions/src/index.ts#L81) (it's a firestore handler function) doesn't get deployed and throws the following error:

```
!  functions: failed to create function devInvoice-sendInvoice
HTTP Error: 400, Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "children" at 'function': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "exit" at 'function': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "message" at 'function': Cannot find field.
```

I am running the latest version of `firebase-tools`: v8.9.0

I tried updating the dependencies to their latest versions:

`firebase-functions`: v3.11.0 
`firebase-admin`: v9.1.1
`stripe`: v8.89.0

Still the same error persists.

Comment: If you are creating a json in your requests, I believe that you could be setting wrong the json attributes, maybe they need to be written differently (check capital letters or typos) Also all the client APIs send the request to the specific endpoints, If you could try to send the specific request to the endpoint, it would be easier for you to test what is failing in your json (basically I would check my request and make sure that the fields needed for it, are the correct ones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny - I came across this because I was doing exactly the same thing (only in my case, using firestore-stripe-subscriptions).

If you run the following, it provides a clue to the error message:

```
firebase deploy --only functions --debug
```

The issue is a missing trigger.

Oddly, I found that the root cause appears to be an error in the Stripe source (at least that's what appeared to be blocking my deployment...)

Changing the https handler from:

```
functions.handler.https.onRequest
```

to

```
functions.https.onRequest
```

Resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I had already changed functions.handler.https.onRequest to functions.https.onRequest, so that had worked before. But the function to send invoice was functions.handler.firestore.document.onCreate, which isn't valid anymore (acc to the debug log), so changing that to functions.firestore.document(path).onCreate worked.

Comment: I don't know why they haven't removed the handler functions from the exports and the typings yet if it's not supported anymore.

Comment: I logged an issue with the extension: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues/54

Interestingly enough, it seems that this is a distinction between how firebase functions work for 'extensions' vs how they are authored directly by developers for deployment via firebase CLI.

Comment: That clarifies it. However, this doesn't seem to be that great a design because it would add complexity for developers who want to customize it, as we would be unable to make quick modifications, don't you feel?

Comment: I has a similar issue with functions.auth.handler.user.onDelete which should be functions.auth.user().onDelete